# Azure AD login session time out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have implemented openid connect authentication using azure active directory in my website. The session expires every 1 hour. So the user is logged out, and redirected back to the login page. While analyzing based on it, i have found a solution in the below link, to use `UseTokenLifetime = false`

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/147

Will this fix my issue? or is there any chance of increasing the session time?

Thanks in advance

Dinesh

Answer (score -1):

Read here to learn more about [Configurable Token Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

In general, access tokens have a very short lifetime. This is intentional. Your web application should be using the **refresh token** which comes with your access token to acquire new access tokens once the original one expires.

When you get an access token and refresh token (assuming all default settings), the access token will last up to one hour. The refresh token will allow you to get a new access token + refresh token pair for up to 14 days. The new refresh token you get will last another 14 days, allowing you to chain new access tokens up to a total of 90 days, where you will need to eventually ask the user to sign in again.

You have the ability to configure token lifetimes such that your "refresh token chain" will never expire, however any individual access token or refresh token will eventually expire.